# No delegateCommandHandler for vscode.java.test.search.items

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Java Test Runner 0.24.2

I cannot see the CodeLens in my vscode editor and the Test Explorer is empty

[Like this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing) and [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/470#issuecomment-444681714), but not work for me, just get

> No delegateCommandHandler for vscode.java.test.search.items

my `.classpath`

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I get it!

Java Test Runner 0.24.2 not work java 1.8

I need downgrade to 0.24.0 ...